# Ruby on Rails search Postgres JSON field globally

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Is there a way to search RoR's postgres json field globally?

The json field has no fixed structure and I don't know its keys and structure.

I want to search whether any keys or any values inside json field contains a keyword. Or, is there a way to convert the json to be a string and search the string for a particular keyword?

Comment: How do you usually work with that data when it has no structure and you do not know what keywords exist? Would you mind elaborating and giving examples?

Comment: It has various structures. When we use it in a specific case, we know its structure. Unfortunately, it has too many cases, each case has a diff structure. Now, we want to search across all cases.

Comment: Is the column JSON or JSONB? Just a simple hash? Or complex nested hashes or nested hashes in arrays?

Comment: You can check [this issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/179598/how-can-i-use-a-full-text-search-on-a-jsonb-column-with-postgres), it is the same.